# Website converted to Web Application - Problems with Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms

I have a website that a converted into a web application running ASP.NET webforms.

The conversion has gone OK and I can run it locally in the Azure emulator, making use of Azure compute and the Azure blob storage.

However, when I come to publish the application to Azure, it gets stuck on "waiting to initialize" constantly (for 3 hours). At this point, I can RDP into the instance but there are no logs in the error log.

IIS has been created, and the website sits in e:\ drive as expected. From the local RDP I cannot view the website (404) and in the Azure management portal it just sits at the initializing stage with an aborted time updating on each refresh.

How do I know what the issue is?

Comment: One of the common reason this to happen is incorrect connection string for storage or diagnostics. Double check them.

Comment: I've removed the enable diagnostics checkbox, so I don't think that would be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It usually happens with a bad web.config and/or missing dependencies.

Here is what you can do with it.

1. Go to properties of every reference in your project and set 'copy local' to true.
2. Double/triple check every config section in you web.config. Make sure you are pointing to right databases (if any).
3. Make sure any of your component is not making direct disk calls on Azure. There is a way to provision them in Azure, it is just that you have to take care of some extra plumbing in 'local resources' settings in your azure project properties.
4. If you are using SQL Azure, make sure your firewall on the database instance is setup to allow calls from your compute instance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wouldn't these things (Excluding the point 1) cause issues even in the local emulator? That works fine.

Comment: Do you have different deployment settings for Prod vs Debug builds? These can cause issues. Open up the package you created from VS and take a look at the DLLs and the web.config

Answer (score 1):

These are typically starup issues or issues with references libraries. Do you have any start-up tasks?

I would one by one remove start-up tasks, activites you do in the WebRole.cs file and go from there. Very frustrating I know, I have spent many days trying to find out issues sometimes

Comment: I only have application_startup code in the global.asax, but this should just throw an exception if it can't connect to the database. I've set the storage up as using storage account credentials, my name part in the url of name.blob.core.windows.net and the primary access key. There isn't anything in WebRole.cs

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have mentioned in your problem description I assume that:

1. You could RDP to your Azure Instance
2. And after remote into you Azure VM, you open webpage using internal IP address i.e. http://10.x.x.x/
3. And you get an error with 404 (file not found - standard HTTP error message)

Sometime the website does now have a default page setup i.e. default.aspx or index.aspx and  tries to open default page with http://10.x.x.x/ base URL and generate error. What if you try to open a page which you know is there i.e. http://10.x.x.x/somepage.aspx. As long as somepage.aspx is there in the webroot it should open in browser.

Because your Web Role is not in Ready state i believe there are some other problem with your role. Here are lots of things to try to root cause:

1. Check the event log for any recorded exception because role is initializing I am sure you may be able to get some exception in Event Log
2. Look at C:\Logs\ folder for any exception related with AzureBootStrapper or IISConfigurator
3. Try to match the E:\AppRoot with your development machine \package\ to see if you have any missing reference (this problem will be logged in Event Log also)
4. I am not sure how your code has dependency on Azure Blob Storage however if you have something in your startup to depend on Azure Blob Storage please verify from Azure VM that you do have connection to there

Based on my extensive experience digging inside Azure VM the problem could be hard to guess or write as answer because every case could be very different and we mostly can provide a very general guideline to root cause.